# Embedding the full $U(n) \subset Spin(2n)$?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry

We can show that $U(n) \subset SO(2n)$. For example, we can see for a $n$-dimensional complex $\mathbb{C}$ vector:
$$
Z_j=X_j +i Y_j
$$
for $j=1,\dots, n$ being acted by the rank-$n$ $U(n)$ matrix representation, we can map
$$Z_j=X_j +i Y_j \text{ acted by } U(n) \to (X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n, 
Y_1, \dots, Y_j, \dots, Y_n) \text{ acted by } SO(n).$$
The $2n$-dimensional real $\mathbb{R}$ vector $(X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n, 
Y_1, \dots, Y_j, \dots, Y_n)$ can be acted (or transformed) by the rank-$2n$ $SO(2n)$ matrix representation.

We see that the invariance of $U(n)$ from two vectors $Z'$ and $Z$
$$
Z'^* \cdot Z\equiv (\dots,X_j' -i Y_j',\dots)\cdot(\dots,X_j +i Y_j,\dots) 
=\sum_{j} (X_j'X_j + Y_j' Y_j)+ i (- Y_j'X_j + X_j'  Y_j)= \text{invariant}, 
$$
contains both the constraints from the $SO(2n)$ invariant:
$$
\sum_{j} (X_j'X_j + Y_j' Y_j)= \text{invariant},
$$
but also
$$
\sum_{j} (- Y_j'X_j + X_j'  Y_j)= \text{invariant}.
$$

> **My puzzle:** Can we prove that $$U(n) \subset Spin(2n)?$$ or prove $$U(n) \not \subset Spin(2n)?$$ Note $U(n)=(SU(n)\times U(1))/(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: The inclusion $U(n)\rightarrow SO(2n)$ is surjective on $\pi_1$, which means that $U(n)$ itself doesn't lift, but rather that the double cover of $U(n)$ is inside of $Spin(2n)$.  I do not know one way or another whether or not the double cover of $U(n)$ is isomorphic to $U(n)$ for general $n$, but for $n=2$, they are definitely different Lie groups.  And of course, this doesn't touch on the question of whether or not there some other embedding of $U(n)$ into $Spin(2n)$ (though I suspect that there not.)

Comment: It will be nice if there is a definite answer or hint... many thanks ~

Comment: hi guys - could you perhaps help math.stackexchange.com/q/4217648/955245 ?

Comment: also  math.stackexchange.com/q/4217668/955245

Comment: @Jason, and hi all, Here is a paper on the double cover of U(n) https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9911028 I am not sure how useful it will be

Comment: Here is a post https://mathoverflow.net/q/94535/27004 on the Representation of double cover of (). I am not sure whether the Spin(2n) contains such a double cover of U(n)? likely not.... unless someone proves it